# Bash: quote expansion in variables (cURL example)

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to run some REST API call via curl, but I'm facing some issue when it comes to generating that curl command using bash.

Please see my example code:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURL_ARGS="-H \"Content-Type: application/json\" --data @somefile.json"
# further variables are set here as well

set -o xtrace   # print command before execution
curl -k -X ${PROTOCOL} -u "${CICD_USER}:${CICD_PW}" ${CURL_ARGS} ${URL} -v
```

Output of xtrace:

```
+ curl -k -X POST -u redacted:redacted -H '"Content-Type:' 'application/json"' --data @somefile.json https://redacted/rest/v1/group/import -v
```

The curl command obviously fails because `${CURL_ARGS}` is not resolved correctly.

I'm confused about the expansion of `${CURL_ARGS}`. Why is the string expanded to `-H '"Content-Type:' 'application/json"'`?

What I'd expect is to generate the curl command like this:

```
curl -k -X POST -u redacted:redacted -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @somefile.json https://redacted/rest/v1/group/import -v
```

Comment: The shell expands variables *after* parsing quotes and escapes, so this doesn't work; either use an array, or just don't store multiple arguments in a single variable. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables) (but avoid all suggestions involving `eval`).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I updated my script and now use the `${var:+..}` parameter expansion, which works fine. I have to admit that I still don't really understand how that variable expansion, parsing and escaping works, but I found a solution that does the job...